# Html color in mdframed

Tags: color, mdframed, html

I want to make mdframed with linecolor set using HTML color model. How can i do it?
I want something like

```
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=\color[HTML]{FF0013}]
    text
\end{mdframed}
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at the `xcolor` package. Not sure if it is possible to specify a color like that though. But it does seem to know the HTML color model

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the simplest is to load `xcolor` with option `svgnames`: the svg colour names are the html colours names. So you can write:

```
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=DarkSeaGreen]
    text
\end{mdframed}
```

To use the HTML hexacimal code, you first have to define your colour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{myframecolour}{HTML}{FF0013}

\begin{document}

    \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=DarkSeaGreen, linewidth = 2pt]
     Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \end{mdframed}

    \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=myframecolour, linewidth = 2pt]
     Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]